# Update if exists else Insert, but with non-unique columns

Tags: mysql, sql-update, on-duplicate-key

I know that I can use "`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`" when I want to update a row if exists, or insert otherwise. 
But in my case, I want to update based on non-unique keys.

**E.g:** I have a table with 3 columns: A, B and C. All of them together form the unique key.
Now I want to update the row if the value of B and C match, or else insert a new row.

Can this be done in MySQL without multiple queries.

Comment: Presumably you mean "columns", instead of "rows"?  If you always update (instead of insert) when the columns match, surely you end up effecting a uniqueness constraint anyway - so why not include it in your schema?  Or are there occasions when you will insert irrespective of existing "duplicate" records?

Comment: no the uniqueness is never broken

Comment: Well if A,B,C together would form a unique key - how would you select the row you want to update when B and C match you can have more than one updated. That's why ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE won't work. If you say you just update all matching rows, you will cause a duplicate key error

Comment: well the logic is such that in certain cases B and C match only one row, and I wanna update only that row

Comment: I say you can't do that in one query if you don't wrap that into a function or procedure

Answer (score 0):

If there were unique keys, you could use REPLACE INTO. If you don't have these unique values, you need to use two queries. Query 1 is a select for update, query two is either an update (if the count of rows returned is > 0) or an insert (if no rows were returned)